# RSA__encryption

Tags: rsa

while trying to login into a site I've stumbled upon having to send a piece of text encrypted with RSA being given two parameters - a 1024 byte long pub key modulus (512characlers) and a pub key exp:

`publickey_mod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
publickey_exp = 010001`

After encoding, we should be left with something like:

`DtvB78BFPVRquP5fQ7CTrdlFboOG3AM5MA3yDKfdZyZbQuCQJL5vaht7XM721D%2BB8kUvG8ZVP%2Bif15ZeusZjikjAvjK%2BrlhoNJmYMnDIZ7avebvYi9PwiegjiEukfgm5dDKJ7Zn%2BRXXog543qPSSGjAj0hhHJFiRP1z33NwBqQbSQFcCxi%2FG4GWFKBomB%2FHqV3wnBDaW8N%2Brx%2FZxUIF1Q2k7SrtGgYr%2FT29ZuEqlEFyM%2FgiAgdk8jO%2F4h0rs%2FuB0lvG4NGhfp4%2BvGDAQ9iCvhwIsGFmwmqB%2Ff1oxhAcSpr8npWRePw3SZLlpoNT31pU9lSPUbvhAg8Hh2S83L9kotw%3D%3D`

Any ideas?

Comment: RSA padding is randomized (the ciphertext changes every time you encrypt the same thing), so you cannot check compatibility in this way. You would have to produce a ciphertext in one environment and try to decrypt it in another to see if you get the original plaintext.

Comment: There is something wrong with your numbers. The modulus presented here has 512 Hex characters which is 256 bytes or 2048 bits.

Comment: If just the password is encrypted then you should be able to login by simply sending the already encrypted password to the service (replay attack). It could be that they use the randomness in the padding to log previous login attempts though (hash over the encrypted value).

Comment: Yes, exactly. The server would need to decrypt the ciphertext using its own private key. That is the correct way to use RSA, but in your question you have an "expected" ciphertext (which was presumably created with a public key) and you're trying to encrypt a password again with that public key. I'm only saying that it is almost impossible to get the same ciphertext that way due to random RSA padding.

Comment: So you're trying to log in to Steam. Is this login procedure documented somewhere? If not, then you're likely violating the terms of service. If yes, then you should use that information to stop guessing about the procedure.

Comment: I haven't reverse-engineered Steam's client side code to see how it works. I can't help you here.

Answer (score -1):

The Base64 encoded string is further URL encoded. You can skip the steps of manually replacing the `+`, `/` and `=` by using java's URLEncoder:

```
  encrypted = URLEncoder.encode(encrypted,
          java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

More details in : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: This is nothing more than a comment (improvement). How exactly does this address the problem in this question?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'd assumed that the question was related to the encoding, which was correct but could be made easier to read. If the asker clarifies with actual result vs. expected I'll improve. I don't have the rep to add a comment, sorry.